# Nvidia prime GPU-only mode stuck at 60 Hz

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I am using a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 and I have the latest NVidia drivers installed. When I set display mode to GPU only in the bios I can have a refresh rate of 240 Hz. I want to set it to hybrid mode so that I can easily switch between "Power Saving" mode (Intel iGPU only) and "Performance Mode" (Nvidia GPU only for gaming).

I can do that using Nvidia prime which is automatically installed with the nvidia drivers. The "On Demand" mode works without any problems, however after enabling the "Performance Mode" (which should disable the intel iGPU) and restarting the refresh rate is stuck at 60 Hz in Gnome Control Center (weirdly there are two 60 Hz options).

I also noticed in the minecraft video settings that the available resolutions seem to match with the capacities of the intel iGPU :

- 2560x1440@60
- 2048x1152@60
- 1920x1440@60
- 1920x1200@60
- 1920x1080@60
- ...
- 1440x810@120

But ingame (F3) it says Display : "Nvidia GeForce RTX 4060 Laptop GPU/PCIe/SSE2..." so it should be using the dGPU and not the iGPU

### More info

In BIOS dGPU-only mode the only available display resolutions in minecraft are 2560x1440@240 and 2560x1440@60.

#### Xrandr -q output in [BIOS Hybrid mode with Nvidia Prime Performance mode enabled] after a reboot

```
$ xrandr -q 
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   2560x1440     60.00*+  60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     60.00  
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     60.00  
   1400x1050     60.00  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     60.00  
   1400x900      60.00  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1280x800      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.00  
   896x672       60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.00  
   840x525       60.00  
   864x486       60.00  
   700x525       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x512       60.00  
   700x450       60.00  
   640x480       60.00  
   720x405       60.00  
   684x384       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00  
   480x270       60.00  
   400x300       60.00  
   432x243       60.00  
   320x240       60.00  
   360x202       60.00  
   320x180       60.00  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

#### Xrandr -q output in [BIOS dGPU only mode]

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   2560x1440     60.00 + 240.00*
```

- If I understand correctly the xrandr -q output should be the same when using BIOS dGPU-only mode and when using BIOS Hybrid Mode with Prime Performance Mode enabled ?
- How to have 240 Hz enabled in BIOS Hybrid mode with Nvidia Prime Performance Mode ?
- Should I use Bumblebee instead ?